# MacVim: make URLs clickable

Tags: macos, macvim

I want to be able to click on URLs I see in MacVim. How can I do that? Is that possible?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers on [MacVim Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_mac/7uXkwq7kJ_4), it seems like this does not exist yet and maybe this would also be better done at Vim-level, i.e. not MacVim specific.

I implemented it myself as a Vim script [here](https://github.com/albertz/vim-mouseclick).